# How to compress a png file with Apache Commons-imaging

Tags: java, png, apache-commons

I'm trying to read/write a PNG using Apache Commons-imaging.

Filename : big-buck-bunny-1080p.png    (1920*1080)

Size : 1,45 Mo (1 527 631 octets)

I'm using java-image-scaling  to scale my images.

For this test, I try to scale my file with the same width and height as the source and write the result to png.

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fileIn);
    ResampleOpSingleThread resampleOp = new ResampleOpSingleThread(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
    resampleOp.setUnsharpenMask(AdvancedResizeOp.UnsharpenMask.Normal);

    BufferedImage resizedImage = resampleOp.filter(image, null);

    final Map<String, Object> writeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    writeParams.put(PngConstants.PARAM_KEY_FORMAT, ImageFormat.IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG);
    writeParams.put(PngConstants.PARAM_KEY_PNG_FORCE_TRUE_COLOR, Boolean.TRUE);
    //writeParams.put(PngConstants.PARAM_KEY_COMPRESSION, TiffConstants.TIFF_COMPRESSION_LZW);

    byte bytes[] = Imaging.writeImageToBytes(resizedImage, ImageFormat.IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG, writeParams);

    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileOut, bytes);
```

but the problem the output file is too big :

2,53 Mo (2 655 456 octets)

What do I need to compress the png file ?

If I use the library the output the file info. I obtains this :

```
Format Details: Png
Bits Per Pixel: 24
Comments: 0
Format: PNG
Format Name: PNG Portable Network Graphics
Compression Algorithm: PNG Filter
Height: 1080
MimeType: image/png
Number Of Images: 1
Physical Height Dpi: -1
Physical Height Inch: -1.0
Physical Width Dpi: -1
Physical Width Inch: -1.0
Width: 1920
Is Progressive: false
Is Transparent: false
Color Type: RGB
Uses Palette: false
```

I took the sample here : http://static.pcinpact.com/images/bd/news/93707-big-buck-bunny.png

I obtain the same problem with this code

```
BufferedImage image = Imaging.getBufferedImage(new File("./src/test/resources/big-buck-bunny-1080p.png"));

Imaging.writeImage(image, new File("output.png"), ImageFormat.IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG, null);
```

Here is the original file : http://postimg.org/image/xob1ss6gj/

here the output file from the snipet above (read, write) : http://postimg.org/image/qu0r33dtf/

Comment: What source? Do you get better results with an image editing app?

Comment: What is the format of the original image? It may be indexed, and you convert it explicitly to RGB which is almost always considerably larger. Or your filtering makes it significantly worse to compress.

Comment: I updated my question. Added more details

Comment: you dont show where imageDimension comes from. Are you sure you are scaling to the same size as the original? Care to show us the result image?

Comment: OK, I'll try to upload the files somewhere.  But for now, you can check the code above.  THe last snipet, it's only read file to BufferedImage and write it back.

Comment: It might be the case that Imaging is not very clever to optimize PNG encoding (it's not a trivial thing).

Comment: @Ibalazscs When I use Gimp, the file size is like the original.